# How to use EM in bootstrap instead of PX for zoom text only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage where I have labels and buttons and they overlap when I do "zoom text only" with firefox and zooms in. After some research it seems because I am zooming in on the text the PX baseline changes which disrupts the @media PX width the bootstrap has so those changes wont be affected. I tried to manually change the PX to EM for the width constraints and then zoom with Text only and I saw the page automatically adjusting. However, I don't want to change the bootstrap to use EM instead of PX which it already has... is there someway I can set in another css file which overrides it so I can zoom correctly when I zoom text only? thanks!

example in bootstrap:
@media(min-width: 76em){
.container{ max-width: 1170px;}
.col-lg1 etc....

instead of 
@media(min-width: 1200px){
.container{ max-width: 1170px;}
.col-lg1 etc....

if I change the 1200px to 76em zoom in with text seems to work. but I don't want to modify the bootstrap directly though...

Comment: Zooming breaks webpages generally; sad but true: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-browser-zooming The problem isn't limited to Bootstrap.

Comment: is there a way to override it though or force bootstrap to use EM?

Comment: Yeah, you could go change the relevant `screen` variables in `variables.less` and recompile Bootstrap from source.

Comment: i am still confused... when I zoom in as text only it seems only the CSS height is changing not the width. So I Created :
@media (min-height: 1000px){
.container{
max-width:1900px; //just to test if it gets called
}
}
but nothing happens when I zoom in. I am really confused here... All I want is to have the same effect that Bootstrap.css gives when I zoom all when I am zoom in text only.... Maybe I need to change the font size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude some text from browser zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586989/how-to-exclude-some-text-from-browser-zoom)